# Scrolling to part of page with href='/subpage', not href='#foo' (JQuery?)

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, seo, scroll

If you have a look here http://www.mcgarrybowen.com/en/ and click in the top navigation menu, the page will scroll to the part of the page you've clicked.

This is usually done with `href='#foo'`, but here it's `href='/subpage'`. The scrolling animation is no problem in jQuery, but I think the magic is happening maybe with AJAX, which I know nothing about.

Even more interesting, the address bar syncs with these href values both ways; if I navigate to http://www.mcgarrybowen.com/en/people, the page loads then scrolls for me, but also if I manually scroll the address bar updates to the current subpage.

How is this being done? Any particular reason to use this, say for SEO?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dude, take a look at PageScroller.js on that site.

Comment: http://pagescroller.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't using AJAX as no further requests are required to achieve this functionality. There appears to be 2 aspects going on here: scrolling to the required `section` and updating the URL based on the current position.

As Alex pointed out, the scrolling appears to be handled by the PageScroller.js library. I can't say I'm familiar with this particular script, but by looking at the source of the navigation links, you can see that they contain `nav-item-id` data that corresponds to the section they're 'linking' to. e.g.

About link:

```
<a data-nav-item-id="9D8C69C00E8E43D39F18F1B78F073554" href="/en/About">About</a>
```

About section:

```
<section id="about" class="about" data-omgb-item-id="9D8C69C00E8E43D39F18F1B78F073554">
     (content)
</section>
```

I'd suggest there is simply a listener for click events on the navigation links that prevents the default behaviour and scrolls to the relevant section instead.

As for the URL updating based on the section you're viewing, this appears to be handled by [ScrollSpy](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy), which is part of Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: I think that answers it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically what hes doing is getting the length of items in the nav which matches the number of sections on the page. He then gets the position of the section based on which nav item has been clicked.